# ERR CONNECTION RESET in xmlhttprequest for file download

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest

Hi I am running this code to download some ( 4 -5 ) zip files with response set as blob. These calls, approx 5 calls  fire at a time as below code runs in loop. But in a production server whis is aws, it returns CONNECTION RESET in console log after 2 files download. Can anyone highlight what may cause this error. I guess too many request at a time is refused by the server, but not sure. Any help is highly appritiated. Thanks

```
self.ajax_call_1 = function (url, type, callback) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status ==     200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
            }
        }
        xhr.open(type, url, true);
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

Comment: Or Alternatively is there any method to catch this error ie CONNECTION RESET and then repeat the ajax call where it failed. ?

Comment: hi, did you find any solution? Im with the exact same problem

Comment: Also having the same issue with a file upload

Comment: @StephenHendricks I also had been running into this issue in huge file upload, for couple of hours and in my case it was the server back end code is asp.net, so I had to set executionTimeOut value in web.config to resolve this error.

The upload was working on 1 system (with high n/w speed) and not on another system (with slow n/w speed)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in file upload and in AJAX call I was using asp.net service to upload file/s. If you have access to the server that service is hosted on, and if it is ashx or asmx (asp.net services) service, you have to make the following changes to web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" executionTimeout="0"/>
```

Here -

```
executionTimeout="6000" Specifies the maximum number of seconds that a request is allowed to execute before being automatically shut down by ASP.NET. This time-out applies only if the debug attribute in the compilation element is False.
maxRequestLength="102400"    for 1mb=1024  so for 100mb=102400
```

*httpRuntime* goes in `<system.web>`